How to parse a qml like structure in Rust with macro_rules
I play with macro_rules, and i want to parse a text like this :
Node {
x: 0;
y: 0;
width: 200;
height: 200;

            Node {
                x: 0;
                y: 100;
                width: 200;
                height: 200;
    
                Node {
                    x: 0;
                    y: 0;
                    width: 100;
                    height: 100;
                }
            }

}

I have build this macro :
macro_rules! rml {
// `Node` without children
(Node {
x: $x:expr;
y: $y:expr;
width: $width:expr;
height: $height:expr;
}) =\> {{
Element::Node( Node {
x: $x,
y: $y,
width: $width,
height: $height,
children: Vec::new(),
})
}};

    //`Node` with children
    (Node {
        x: $x:expr;
        y: $y:expr;
        width: $width:expr;
        height: $height:expr;
        $($tail:tt)*
    }) => {{
        let elements = rml!( @child $($tail)* );
        Element::Node( Node {
            x: $x,
            y: $y,
            width: $width,
            height: $height,
            children: vec!(elements),
        })
    }};
    
    (@child $($item:tt)* ) => {
        rml!( $($item)* )
    
    };

}

This work well where i have only one node by level, but if i try this :
Node {
x: 0;
y: 0;
width: 200;
height: 200;

            Node {
                x: 0;
                y: 100;
                width: 200;
                height: 200;
            }
    
            Node {
                x: 0;
                y: 0;
                width: 100;
                height: 100;
            }
        }

It all fail.
I understant my macros don't work with this pattern, but i have no idea to fix it.
So, if someone has an idea, it will be very nice !
Thanks !
There is the error :

error: no rules expected the token `Node`
\--\> src/main.rs:90:13
|
26 | macro_rules! rml {
| ---------------- when calling this macro
...
90 |             Node {
|             ^^^^ no rules expected this token in macro call
|
note: while trying to match `}`
\--\> src/main.rs:50:5
|
50 |     }) =\> {{
|     ^

error: could not compile `test_macro` (bin "test_macro") due to 1 previous error

I do this in the macro part that match node with child :
rml!( @child $($tail)\* );
But, i think i'm missing something here.

(@child $($item:tt)\* ) =\> {
rml!( $($item)\* )
};

It work when there is one item at max, but when we have more item, maybe the  }  Node { is not well handled idk.
In fact, i use : rml!( @child $($tail)* );  but, if i understand well * will pass all the rest of the token tree, i would want to split this token tree, but i don't knwo how.
If have try this to try to match the Node { ... } thing :
(@child
$( Node {
$($tail:tt)\*
} )\*
) =\> {
println!("Node children: {:#?}", $($tail)\*);
//rml!( Node { $children } )
};


but it return that :
error: variable `tail` is still repeating at this depth
\--\> src/main.rs:73:44
|
73 |         println!("Node children: {:#?}", $($tail)\*);
|                                            ^^^^^

error: could not compile `test_macro` (bin "test_macro") due to 1 previous error

I have no idea at this point; so any help is appreciated :)

serde_json might be a good start about this kind of macros.
